# Unit Testing RESTapi with Moq Object of type String.String can not be converted to BaseObjectDto

Tags: c#, unit-testing, moq

I am trying to create a unit test of the RESTApi but I am getting an error when I attempt to call the .Get{id} method from the controller.

(The controller is mocked because it is abstract)

I receive the error (in title) when  I get to the last line of the test.

(I have tried Asserts and .Verify()'s but i dont reach them because I error out before I reach them)

I feel like I am missing something small, but then again this is my first time with Moq.

```
    protected CustomActionModelController(IModelProvider<TModel> provider, IModelMapper mapper)
    {
        _mapper = mapper;
        _provider = provider;
        _customActions = new Dictionary<string, Func<string, object, object>>();

        InitializeCustomActions();
    }

    protected abstract void InitializeCustomActions();


    [HttpGet("{id}")]
    [Produces(DefaultContentType)]
    public virtual TDto Get([FromRoute]string Id)
    {
        return ToDto(_provider.Get(Id));
    }



    [TestMethod]
    public void GetWithIdParameterReturnsSingleObject()
    {
        var provider = new Mock<IModelProvider<BaseDomainModel>>();
        var mapper = new Mock<IModelMapper>();
        var services = new Mock<IServiceCollection>();
        var builder = new AutofacBuilder();
        builder.RegisterType<IModelProvider<BaseDomainModel>, FakeDataProvider>().SingletonScope();
        var customMock = new Mock<CustomActionModelController<BaseDomainModel, BaseObjectDto>>(provider.Object, mapper.Object);
        customMock.Setup(x => x.Get(It.IsAny<string>())).Returns((BaseObjectDto s) =>  s = new BaseObjectDto("Test", "test"));
        var actual = customMock.Object.Get("1");
    }
```

Comment: The question in its current state is unclear as it is incomplete. Read [ask] and then provide a [mcve] that can be used to better understand your problem.

Comment: You have `It.IsAny<string>()` in the setup but use `BaseObjectDto` in the returns function.

Comment: Also why mock the method under test. I get mocking the controller because it is abstract but mocking the method under test makes no sense. It is just going to return what was arranged in the setup. You are basically testing the mocking framework

Comment: Spend some time with [Mow Quickstart](https://github.com/Moq/moq4/wiki/Quickstart)

Comment: You would also need to configure the mock to call base members

Comment: @Nkosi I mocked the method like that because without doing that I was getting "object not set" error when I tried to call get.

Comment: because you did not set the mock to call the base method. The method is virtual so Moq overrode it by default.

Answer (score 0):

Do not setup the method under test. Use `CallBase` on the Mock

```
var customMock = new Mock<CustomActionModelController<BaseDomainModel, BaseObjectDto>>(provider.Object, mapper.Object) {
    // Whether the base member virtual implementation 
    // will be called for mocked classes if no setup is matched.
    CallBase = true 
};

var actual = customMock.Object.Get("1");
```

Reference [Moq: Quickstart - Customizing Mock Behavior](https://github.com/Moq/moq4/wiki/Quickstart#customizing-mock-behavior)

Comment: I get System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

When I set it up like this

Comment: @GuyA you are going to have to provide a [mcve] in your original post so that the problem can be properly identified. What I suggested should work once you have setup your mock correctly.